# Use Velocity.js or Transit.js for CSS/JS/jQuery animations?

Tags: jquery, animation, jquery-animate, velocity.js, transit

I have been using jQuery's [.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) to animate websites and absolutely love how it works. However I just learned that [Velocity.js](http://julian.com/research/velocity/) and [Transit.js](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) perform way faster, can animate CSS3 transitions and can be used in jQuery just like .animate().

**Should I use [Velocity.js](http://julian.com/research/velocity/) or [Transit.js](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) for animations? And why?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the tests on this page, velocity is the best(gives smoothest animations):
`Speed Test`  http://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/pmknI

Using these libraries greatly increased the smoothness of my animations on mobile devices.

However I've done tests on memory consumption (looking at browser's task manager) and I saw that every time I did the animation with velocity or transit, it used up a lot more memory (3MB) every time I kicked off the animation ( not to mention it took the Garbage Collector a long time to reclaim this memory)

On the other hand calling jQuery's animate used an average 1MB to perform the same animation.